# Data mining or data visualization?

Tags: data-visualization, data-mining

My basic doubt is what is difference between Data mining and Data visualization? 
does they have different algorithms?

I have a machine data stored in database. I have to develop an app which will have a dashboard to show state of machine ( based on time taken by a machines to produce a product. I am very sure that its not predictive analysis. I just have to decide based on the standard values of the machines). So what i really have to do first? data mining and then data visualization ? or otherwise?

My understanding:

I have to study the data base, set some conditions or apply some techniques to decide which machines are working fine and then apply some visualisation technique to show it on dash board. Am I right?

Please correct me if I am wrong and please let me know what is difference between data mining and data visualisation.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up:

**Data mining**: An analytical process that explores data to find patterns or systematic relationships between variables. The main goal of data mining is to predict.

**Data visualization**: as the name might imply, you show the data in a visual object. There's many ways to do this though, most commonly known are graphs and and charts.

The situation you described is most likely a good example of data that needs to be analysed a bit before getting displayed. 
Seeing as data mining is mainly used to make predictions, it does seem rather irrelevant for the current machine state. My guess is that you evaluate the data first to determine the critical variables and then display them, using a form of data visualization, in the dashboard

Comment: So just analyse the variables in the database which can leads to decision and then display, is what your suggestion is? So if else condition would be a good way? how about outlier detection?

Comment: +1 This is a clear, well-stated summary that gets right to the point.  Welcome to our site, Chen!